# Sending udp message from a remote server to my computer via internet

Tags: php, udp, ip-address, private, public

I am trying to send a udp message from a php webpage to my computer and it works if I send it from the localhost, but if I send it from a remote server I will never receive the message. Please advise how to set the ip address, I have public and private ip addresses. I tried `$server_ip` set to both the public and private ip address of my computer but it doesn't work.

```
<?php   
  $server_ip   = '127.0.0.1';
  $server_port = 2009;
  $beat_period = 5;
  $message     = 'Hello world! ';
  print "Sending heartbeat to IP $server_ip, port $server_port\n";
  print "press Ctrl-C to stop\n";
  if ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)) {
    while (1) {
      socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $server_ip, $server_port);
    print "Time: " . date("%r") . "\n";
    sleep($beat_period);
    }
  } else {
    print("can't create socket\n");
  }
?>
```

Please advise ...

Comment: Please provide details about your connection and internet setup. Do you use a router, do you have a NAT, have you opened and forwarded port 2009? etc...

Comment: Thanks Jakub Wrona, it works after adding port forwarding at my D-Link DIR-615 router. I have also set my computer ip address to static ip address but how do I set my router's internet ip address? it keep changing

Comment: Some ISPs offer static IP, check yours. If not you can always use something like dyndns, noip.org etc... but your router has to support it.